# Jumpy Touchscreen, Physical Keyboard available, Cursor for Android?

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

I have an android `Motorola Droid 4` (with physical keyboard, Cyanogenmod 12.1), but the touchscreen is jumpy, for example there are some rows that the touch could not be detected at all.. yesterday it's only 1 row (10% of screen), today is 3 rows (30% of whole screen), so I could not point at those rows..

Is there a cursor for android that can be moved by keyboard arrow keys?

As you can see on the screenshot, there are 3 rows that cannot be selected at all..

[image: untouchable screen]

Comment: [LMT Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150)'s pie-pointer may be able to help: http://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Hkb.png

Comment: You might also wish to check the developer options. I vaguely remember having seen something like that there – but I'm not sure whether that might be specific to CyanogenMod.